# OS X package with multiple domains

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I am looking to create a mpkg that targets installations to both the user home directory and the system volume (for example, plugins in both ~/Library/ and /Library/).

I can only seem to be able to do one or the other (not two together). I also have found virtually no documentation on this subject. Installation domains seems to be glazed over.

Can anyone shed light into this? I have been trying to accomplish this in both PackageMaker.app as well as Packages.app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a custom postflight script to handle the user specific plugins.
I recommend [the luggage](https://github.com/unixorn/luggage) to roll your own pkg with a makefile.